# Row object in RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying For each RDD, remove the header
row and parse each comma-delimited line into a Row object with each column
following the data type given in the jupyter notebook cell. Please convert some
columns into the preferred format. Columns that should be converted into integer :
'YEAR', 'MONTH', 'DAY','DAY_OF_WEEK', 'FLIGHT_NUMBER'. Column that
should be converted into float data type : 'DEPARTURE_DELAY',
'ARRIVAL_DELAY', 'ELAPSED_TIME', 'AIR_TIME', 'DISTANCE', 'TAXI_IN', and
'TAXI_OUT'. While the rest are kept as string format.

Currently this is my code

```
def import_csv_rdd(data):
    rdd = sc.textFile(data)
    rdd_header = 
    # 1. Split each line separated by comma into a list 
    bank_rdd1 = bank_rdd.map(lambda line: line.split(','))
    # 2. Remove the header
    header = bank_rdd1.first()
    bank_rdd1 = bank_rdd1.filter(lambda row: row != header)   #filter out header
```

^ the above code is not finished and needs some adaptation however, i would like to get some clarification in how to "parse each comma-delimited line into a Row object"

Comment: Just really dont understand the "parse each comma-delimited line into a Row object"

Comment: Why don't you read file as dataframe and cast columns with required types?

Comment: Ill be doing that soon but i just wanted to get to know how to generate this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do this with simple file with less columns.

```
col1,col2,col3
1,1.2,value1
2,2.2,value2
```

Reading this file as RDD and change that to Row object after converting col1 type to int, col2 type to float.

```
>>> rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile('/file/path/')

>>> header = rdd.first()
>>> rdd = rdd.filter(lambda row: row != header)
>>> split_rdd = rdd.map(lambda line: line.split(','))

>>> row_rdd = split_rdd.map(lambda line: Row(col1 = int(line[0]), col2=float(line[1]), col3=line[2]))

>>> row_rdd.collect()
[Row(col1=1, col2=1.2, col3='value1'), Row(col1=2, col2=2.2, col3='value2')]
```

Comment: how should i go about fixing the value error could not convert string to float

Comment: for some of the columns it is an empty string, i want to add the value 0 however i am not sure how in spark rdd

Comment: To replace empty string eg-->`col3=0 if "".__eq__(line[2]) else line[2]`

Comment: where should i be putting this in my code?

Comment: `row_rdd = split_rdd.map(lambda line: Row(col1 = int(line[0]), col2=float(line[1]), col3=0 if "".__eq__(line[2]) else line[2]))`

Comment: thank you i was wondering if you could guide me on how to develop my own hash function for hash partioning

Comment: I didn't use custom partitioner. But hope this [link](https://blog.clairvoyantsoft.com/custom-partitioning-spark-datasets-25cbd4e2d818) might help you.

Comment: Hi Mohana if you could take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69143631/rdd-operations-in-pyspark-to-find-query